# Prevent export LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS

Tags: macos, homebrew

I was trying to use homebrew on my Mac yesterday. After installation. several packages i saw a similar message in the terminal

```
If you need to have sqlite first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find sqlite you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include"
```

So I did not hesitate to follow all these recommendations for each package, naturally I didn’t have an idea of what it was and why. After I have done a lot of things, please explain to me what this procedure is for and how obligatory it is. If it is not necessary or, on the contrary, harmful, how can I roll back these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply remove the matching lines from your `~/.zshrc`.